# Fill a cell as plain text

Tags: excel, text, formula

I've got a spreadsheet with trade pricing from one supplier being calculated to retail pricing which all needs to go into a master database with all suppliers and products.

What I want to do is take the retail price (which is calculated with a formula), and copy it (it being the value) to another cell without that cell containing a formula, so I can copy/paste it's content (plain text) to another spreadsheet (the master one) without it referring or relying on the other spreadsheet.

I hope this makes sense?

Comment: Copy the cell with the formula and **PasteSpecialValues** into the other cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Copy` the cell where formula is and then do `Paste Special->Value`.

To do so right click on the cell where you want to paste the value, select `Paste Special` and then click on `Values` radio button  and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I guess this is what you are asking for.

Comment: WONDERFUL! Exactly what I needed! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

On the first spreadsheet, if the retail calculated price column is D1 then add a column with the formula =D1, this will show the value not the formula in D1.

Then you either copy and paste this column into a new spreadsheet, or copy and paste link this column to maintain a link with the first spreadsheet.